# Is `blur` event dispatched by `pointerdown` guaranteed to fire before a user-scheduled task?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Let's say I have a button with a `pointerdown` (or `mousedown`) event handler, in which I schedule a task via `setTimeout` (irrespective of the `delay`).

Is the task guaranteed to execute *after* the `blur` event that fires as a consequence of the `pointerdown` event?

I've skimmed [UI Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-blur) and [Pointer Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/) specs but that didn't help me.

My understanding is that the `blur` event is just another task being scheduled on the event loop *before* the `pointerdown` event handler is invoked, and as such, it's virtually guaranteed that any user-scheduled tasks will fire *after* the `blur` event fires.

Note that by "blur event firing" I mean both the native browser behavior that happens on a `blur` event (such as de-focusing inputs), and user-registered event handlers on that `blur` event. See below example:

```js
window.btn.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
  window.txt.onblur = null;
  setTimeout(() => { // this should be invoked *after* the `blur` event
    window.txt.onblur = () => { // this should never run when clicking on the button
      console.log("blurred");
    };
    window.txt.focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<button id="btn">focus</button>
```

It feels like the answer will be "it's up to the user agent (browser)".

Answer (score 0):

In your example code you simply remove the `onblur` handler for the text field and immediately re-add a new handler.

---

Whether the `blur` event (and its handlers) of the input field or the `pointerdown` event (and its handlers) is pushed onto the event loop probably depends on the browser implementation, since this edge case might not be specified.

Comment: The example is contrived just to illustrate the question. In the real world you generally need to depend on this event order if you can't/don't want to `preventDefault`, and thus have to bind your `blur` event handler after the one from the `pointerdown` fires. I wouldn't say it's an edge case - I have to use these and similar hacks in pretty much every major web app I've built (but only now got around to ask if my experience is backed by spec or not - I guess it's one of the cases of "every browser does the same thing even if unspecced").

Comment: I would suggest to bind both events and uses a shared mutex to make sure the desired events are only handled once, independently of browser behaviour.